# Change path of Uploadform automatically

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

How can I change the path of the uploadform automatically? I always get this error (below).
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UkSG.png)

This is the html upload form (below). I want to upload a file automatically from a path. Is that possible with php, html and javascript?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Agb.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: If this is permitted , then I think someone can easily steal the file(s) from your computer

Comment: You can't select a file / filepath programmatically in a regular web context, that would be a gigantic security issue.

Comment: If you're frequently updating a file and want to keep track of its changes the file system access api might better suit your needs: https://web.dev/file-system-access/